# potential leak of an object without further info

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to repair all the memory leaks in my app. I am having some issues with this line of code

```
[appDelegate setPendingConnectionsArray:[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[response JSONValue]]];
```

Here **PendingConnectionsArray** is an NSArray defined in **appDelegate**. When i analyze my app using analyzer tool of XCode. then it says potential leak of an object but no further information is there. How can i solve this leak issue.

Situation is same for this line too

```
phone_book_data.contact_image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(aSource)];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the basis that your first line is generating a warning, I presume you're not using ARC? ARC automatically solves those sorts of routine issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to release the array, because you have allocated it.

```
[appDelegate setPendingConnectionsArray:[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[response JSONValue]]autorelease];
```

Comment: Should i use just release or autorelease ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to release  **PendingConnectionsArray** in the dealloc of your **appDelegate**

Comment: If i dalloc PendingConnectionsArray in dealloc of appDelegate then when will it be release exactly while running my app. sorry if my question does n't make any sense.

Comment: I tried your answer but no diference still the situation is same

Answer (score 0):

In your former example, I have to assume you're not using ARC. In such case, you would solve that with:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[response JSONValue]];
[appDelegate setPendingConnectionsArray:array];
[array release];
```

Or with:

```
[appDelegate setPendingConnectionsArray:[[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[response JSONValue]] autorelease]];
```

Or (if the `JSONValue` array is immutable) with:

```
[appDelegate setPendingConnectionsArray:[response JSONValue]];
```

In your latter example, if it was ARC, you'd just transfer ownership and then let it clean up:

```
phone_book_data.contact_image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)CFBridgingRelease(ABPersonCopyImageData(aSource))];
```

But in MRC, you'd probably do:

```
CFDataRef dataRef = ABPersonCopyImageData(aSource);
phone_book_data.contact_image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)(dataRef)];
CFRelease(dataRef);
```

or

```
phone_book_data.contact_image = [UIImage imageWithData:[(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(aSource) autorelease]];
```